# withKeyConditionExpression in DynamoDB enhanced version

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

All - I'm trying to migrate dynamodbclient from v1 to enhancedclient and I'm unable to figure out how I can convert this below line.

In V1 :
queryExpression.withKeyConditionExpression("country = :country and state = :state");
queryExpression.withFilterExpression("dist = :dist");

In V2 with QueryEnhancedRequest, how can I add the above two lines?